# How to set http post parameter

Tags: c

In my project, I need to set http post parameters using "Key=Value" method and cat the parameters using "&".
Example.

```
while () { 
    //Key 
    strcat(PackBuf, Key);
    strcat(PackBuf, "="); 
    //Value
strcat(PackBuf, Value);
}
```

The PackBuf is a large buffer to store data. In the end I get the string like

> id=123456&name=Bill&age=20......

But the problem is

- 1. I have to sort the Key string by ASCII.Do i set it by manual or any other good method?
- 2. When I get the data like "id=123456&name=Bill&age=20......",how can i analyze it?

Comment: HTTP doesn't care about the order of the parameters, why do you need to sort them?

Comment: I have to calculate the SHA1 value.It need the parameters sort in ASCII

Comment: When comparing two checksums, the important thing is that the data you use is the same for both checksums. Ordering the parameters is one way of doing it, but it's not needed as long as the order is the same for both checksums.

Comment: By the way, regarding your second point, what do you mean by "analyzing it"? Split it into key-value pairs and split each pair into its separate keys and values?

Comment: yes.split it into key-value pairs.

Comment: For the second point, you might want to read about [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: Thanks a lot.I got a point from what you said.